A question on linear representation of representable group functors
Let $G =  Hom_{k\text{- alg}}(A,\_)$ be a representable group functor from category of $k$ algebras to category of groups where $k$ is a commutative ring with unity. Let $V$ be a fixed $k$ module. Consider a linear representation $\Phi : G \to GL_V$. Let $g : A \to R$ be an element of $G(R).$
Then I want to show that $\Phi(g) $ is the unique $ R $ - linear map such that the below diagram commutes.

Suppose $\Psi$ is another such map, then we must have $$\Phi(g) \circ (id_V \otimes g)  =  (id_V \otimes g) \circ  \Phi(id_A) = \Psi \circ (id_V \otimes g).$$ Then $$\Phi(g) \circ (id_V \otimes g) = \Psi \circ (id_V \otimes g). $$ Evaluating above expression at $v \otimes 1$ for $ v \in V$ we get $$\Phi(g)(v \otimes 1) = \Psi(v \otimes 1) .$$ Since, both $\Psi$ and $\Phi(g)$ are $R$ linear maps we get $$ \Phi(g)(v \otimes r) = \Psi(v \otimes r) $$ for all $r \in R.$ This implies that $\Phi(g) = \Psi.$
Is this correct? Here I did not use the fact that $ \Phi(g) $ is an $R$ - linear automorphism on $V  \otimes_k  R.$ Am I missing something?
